# How to display images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, blob

When I store my image in mysql it get stored as a blob and when i try to display it the image does not show up. I have tried to find how to display it but had no luck. Can anyone help me. The first piece of code is the form and the next piece which starts with const express is where the data gets sent to the mysql server.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
 
export default class Sell extends Component{
 
   constructor(){
       super()
       this.state={
           img:"",
           dropdownval:'',
           h:1
       }
   }
 
   handleSubmit = e =>{
       e.preventDefault()
       const data={
        tiTle:this.product,
        descripTion:this.description,
        condiTion:this.state.dropdownval,
        quanTity:this.quantity,
        prIce:this.price,
        picTure:this.state.img
       }
 
       axios.post('http://localhost:3001/sell/listing',data).then(
           res  => {
               console.log(res)
           }
       ).catch(
           err=>{
           console.log(err)
           }
       )
       this.setState({
        h:0
    })
   }
 
   onImageChange =(e)=>{
       const [file] = e.target.files
       this.setState({
           img:URL.createObjectURL(file)
       })
   }
 
   onDropdownChange =(e)=>{
       this.setState({ dropdownval:e.target.value });
   }
 
 
 
   render(){
    if(this.state.h===0){
        return <Redirect to={'/'}/>
    }
       return(
           <form className="sellForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               <h3>Sell</h3>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Product Title</label>
                   <input type="text" className="form-control" required
                       onChange={e => this.product= e.target.value}/>
               </div><br/>
 
               <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Description</label><br/>
                   <textarea className="description" type="text" required
                   onChange={e => this.description= e.target.value}/>
               </div><br/>
 
           <label>Condition:</label><br/>
               <select onChange={this.onDropdownChange}>
                   <option value="new">New</option>
                   <option value="slightly-used">Slightly Used</option>
                   <option value="used">Used</option>
               </select>
 
               <div className="form-group">
               <br/><label>Quantity:</label><br/>
                   <input className="form-control" type="number" min="0" required
                   onChange={e => this.price= e.target.value}/>
               </div><br/>
 
               <div className="form-group">
               <label>Price:</label><br/>
                   <span>$</span>
                   <input className="form-control" type="number" min="0" required
                   onChange={e => this.quantity= e.target.value}/>
               </div><br/>
 
               <div className="form-group">
                   <br/><label className="img-label">Insert Image</label>
                   <input type="file" onChange={this.onImageChange}/>
                   <img className="sellImg"src={this.state.img}/>
               </div><br/>
 
               <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                   Upload Listing
               </button>
           </form>
       )
   }
}


const express = require("express")
const bodyParser=require("body-parser")
const app = express();
const cors=require("cors")
const mysql = require("mysql");

app.post("/sell/listing",(req,res)=>{
    const title = req.body.tiTle
    const description = req.body.descripTion
    const condition = req.body.condiTion
    const quantity = req.body.quanTity
    const price = req.body.prIce
    const pic = req.body.picTure
    sqlInsert="INSERT INTO listings (name,price,description,condi,quantity,picture) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    db.query(sqlInsert,[title,price,description,condition,quantity,pic], (err,result)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
 })
 
 app.get("/api/get", (req, res) => {
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM listings";
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
 
 
app.listen(3001, () =>{
    console.log("running on port 3001");
});
 
 
const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "cruddatabase",
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: You probably want to use [blob.arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) or [blob.stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream)

Comment: i added a picture of my code